# NTDSUTIL and Operation Master roles questions (or what port is DC stuff replicated over)

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

I know how to find what Domain Controller's have roles using the GUI tools in windows, now I'm trying to make sure I can do it from the command line.  Below is what I'm trying but its not working -- I believe I'm missing a port number.. but what is the default port number?

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> ntdsutil
C:\Windows\system32\ntdsutil.exe: roles
fsmo maintenance: connections
server connections: mydc.fqdn.dom
Error parsing Input - Invalid Syntax.
server connections:
```

I'm pretty sure the syntax is supposed to be

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> ntdsutil
C:\Windows\system32\ntdsutil.exe: roles
fsmo maintenance: connections
server connections: mydc.fqdn.dom:port
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Great article](http://www.petri.co.il/determining_fsmo_role_holders.htm) that lists several methods to get your FSMO details